# Prophet CMDStanpy error - Procedure Entry Point Not Located

Tags: python, model-fitting, prophet

I am trying to use prophet library.

The 'cmdstanpy' and 'prophet' packages are successfully installed. But I am getting this error while running my model - "The procedure entry point _ZNt3bb19task_scheduler_init10initilaizeEiy could not be located in the dynamic link library D:/ProgramData/ Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/prophet/stan_model/prophet_model.bin"

I tried the steps mentioned here https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/2255

like creating new virtualenv and installing prophet in that env and running it also installing cmdstanpy but I am still facing the issue.

Yesterday I was able to resolve the same issue in base environment with the following steps

```
pip install  cmdstanpy
Then in the libs import section, I've added
import cmdstanpy
cmdstanpy.install_cmdstan(compiler=True)
```

But today I am again getting same issue in base and any other virtual environment.

Please help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally what worked for me :

on conda prompt activate the environment using

```
conda activate envname
```

then I ran this to install as per documentation https://mc-stan.org/cmdstanpy/installation.html

```
conda install -c conda-forge cmdstanpy
```

and import cmdstanpy in code

not sure of the reason why it works and earlier it wasn't working though.